# Will completing the Dark Brotherhood quest chain hinder any significant quests/events?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have an overall planned story for my character, part of which runs through the Dark Brotherhood. One of the first sets of contracts you do for them include killing one person that I know starts a small quest (very small in this case). I am wondering if I should be aware of any significant events that these contracts might remove from the game. Hover the spoiler to see the small one I mention above.

For what its worth, Google led me to a few articles on reasons not to join the Dark Brotherhood that all ended up being speculation, and a post on the gamefaq forums that also did not provide useful information.

> One of the first people you kill is Narfi who's sister you can search for if you are not out to get him. This is a very short/minor quest (with not too bad rewards actually) however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, none of the Dark Brotherhood's quests intersect in any meaningful way with any other quest chain. Some targets may have minor 'radiant' quests available, but none are significant in any way.

The worst thing that can happen is you can end up with a very large bounty on your head, which could make completing other quests... difficult at best. However, this is both a solvable, and preventable problem.

The only collision other than the one you've noted, is that

> [Vittoria Vici](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vittoria_Vici), the target of the main-line quest Bound Until Death is also involved in the *incredibly minor* quest [The Spiced Wine.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Spiced_Wine)

Comment: A quick and direct answer, Greatly Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Marked as the answer for including the second person affected by the line, even if she is just as minor as the one I mentioned :)

Answer (score 7):

For the side contracts offered by Nazir, none of the targets offer anything unique except for Narfi (whom you've mentioned). Some of them, like Betild or Anoriath, will offer or be the target of another radiant quest (mine ore, companions quest, etc), but Narfi is the only one with a unique one.

Some of these targets are vendors, but none of them are particularly useful to adventurers (Anoriath sells 10 random pieces of meat, for instance), nor do they have particularly large purses.

Finally, the Dark Brotherhood Radiant quests (after completing the quest line) use generic NPCs, such as "Noblemen", so once you've completed the initial quests, you will not be tasked to kill random named NPCs.

My advice? Do Narfi's quest, then put the poor fellow out of his misery, as gently as possible.

Comment: +1 for a bit more of an explanation as to where it all leads you.

Answer (score 5):

I would say no, other than if you join the Dark Brotherhood, you very well can't [Destroy the Dark Brotherhood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destroy_the_Dark_Brotherhood!).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will. [Blood on the Ice](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice) is a fairly major side quest taking place in Windhelm. I consider the quest to be pretty important part of the lore of the town.

> Although most of the NPCs needed for the quest to initiate are marked as essential, another quest, namely the **Dark Brotherhood quest Mourning Never Comes**, will encourage you to kill Nilsine Shatter-Shield. Even though she is not related to this quest, her mother, Tova Shatter-Shield, will commit suicide if Nilsine is killed, and will therefore render this quest impossible to initiate.